# Instr function cannot detect a word inside a string

Tags: string, function, excel, named-ranges, vba

In this private function I want to set a worksheet if the following requirements are met:

1. Cell Z1 has to contain the Word `Special_Sheet`
2. In `Special_sheet` the cell defined as `Description` has to contain either `turn` or `TRN`.

But it doesn't register the Words `turn` or `TRN`. Am I using the `InStr` function incorrectly?

```
Private Function getTransferSheet() As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Range("Z1") <> "Special_Sheet" Then GoTo ContLoop

        If InStr(1, ws.Range("Description"), "turn", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, ws.Range("Description"), "TRN", vbTextCompare) Then
            Set getTransferSheet = ws
            Exit Function
        End If
    ContLoop:
    Next

    MsgBox "Turn sheet (Last sheet) not found", vbExclamation
    End
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

`InStr` function returns an int. There you want a boolean.
Also I don't think you want to set `start`, if so don't set it. Also you have to get the `Text` of the `Range("Description")`

Try :

```
If InStr(ws.Range("Description").Text, "turn", vbTextCompare) <> 0  Or InStr(ws.Range("Description").Text, "TRN", vbTextCompare) <>0 Then
```

Comment: Hi @ZwoRmi. I tried to set it to <> 0 but it still isn't working.

Comment: @Saud Did you try to use the debugger?

Comment: Sry, I'm not the best at debugging :/. When I Togle Breakpoint and run through the code, it is skipping the second if statement (with the special Words)

Comment: @Saud So toggle a breakpoint on the `if` line, run the code, when your code is stopped select `ws.Range("Description")`, right click and then `Add watch`, you will see the value.

Comment: When I do that, I get Value: <Out of context>. Type: Empty

Comment: @Saud you have to  `add watch` when execution is stopped on the breakpoint line (When there is a yellow arrow). If you don't know how to use the debugger, so Google it, or ask another question.

Comment: In the watch window, It is reading all the values in the "Description" cell, also the one containing "UF" but the code is not run correctly. I guess it shouldn't make any difference if I delete "1" in the beginning and "vbTextCompare" in the end. Just tried.

Comment: `instr` expects the starting index as the first argument - you cannot just leave it out. `instr(range().value,...)` would try to use the text value of the cell as the starting index and fail.

Comment: @user1016274 The `start` argument is optional.

Answer (score 0):

The original code is correct in regard to the `instr` instruction. Compare with this:

```
Function getTransferSheet() As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim test As String

    Set getTransferSheet = Nothing
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Range("Z1") = "Special_Sheet" Then
            test = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            test = ws.Range("Description").Text
            On Error GoTo 0
            If InStr(1, test, "turn", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, test, "TRN", vbTextCompare) Then
                Set getTransferSheet = ws
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This will work even if the named range 'description' doesn't exist. Otherwise, the `instr` function will fail as the comparison needs 2 strings. 
You are right to use the `vbTextCompare` option - it makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Finally, I have refactored the code to provide a clean path of execution in all cases, even if a transfer sheet cannot be determined. There should be only one exit in a function, and it should consistently return one data type. If you want to react on failures, do so in the calling routine:

```
' code where this function is called
set ws = getTransferSheet
If ws is Nothing then
    MsgBox "Turn sheet (Last sheet) not found", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
```